# How can I find unique characters per line of input?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

Is there any way to extract the unique characters of each line?

I know I can find the unique lines of a file using

```
sort -u file
```

I would like to determine the unique characters of each line (something like `sort -u` for each line).

To clarify: given this input:

```
111223234213
111111111111
123123123213
121212122212
```

I would like to get this output:

```
1234
1
123
12
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using sed

```
sed ':;s/\(.\)\(.*\)\1/\1\2/;t' file
```

Basically what it does is capture a character and check if it appears anywhere else on the line. It also captures all the characters between these. 
Then it replaces all of that including the second occurence with just first occurence and then what was inbetween.

`t` is test and jumps to the `:` label if the previous command was successful. Then this repeats until the `s///` command fails meaning only unique characters remain.

`;` just separates commands.

```
1234
1
123
12
```

Keeps order as well.

Comment: This is shorter! What are `:;` and `t` do?

Comment: @user1436187 Added explanation

Comment: This can be shortened and made more perhaps quicker so: `sed ':;s/\(\(.\).*\)\2/\1/g' file` . However it should be remembered that it removes duplicate symbols but does not sort them too.

Comment: @potong That does not work for me. I also can't see how it would work or why you have a label at the front but nothing jumping to it. Can you explain the command please ?

Comment: My mistake `sed ':;s/\(\(.\).*\)\2/\1/g;t' file`.

Comment: This produces `sed: -e expression #1, char 1: ":" lacks a label`

Comment: @Riot Change to `sed ':1;s/\(.\)\(.*\)\1/\1\2/;t1'` or use  a newer version of sed.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't get things in the original order, but this awk one-liner seems to work:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=length($0);i++){a[substr($0,i,1)]=1} for(i in a){printf("%s",i)} print "";delete a}' input.txt
```

Split apart for easier reading, it could be stand-alone like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{
  # Step through the line, assigning each character as a key.
  # Repeated keys overwrite each other.
  for(i=1;i<=length($0);i++) {
    a[substr($0,i,1)]=1;
  }

  # Print items in the array.
  for(i in a) {
    printf("%s",i);
  }

  # Print a newline after we've gone through our items.
  print "";

  # Get ready for the next line.
  delete a;
}
```

Of course, the same concept can be implemented pretty easily in pure bash as well:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read s; do
  declare -A a
  while [ -n "$s" ]; do
    a[${s:0:1}]=1
    s=${s:1}
  done
  printf "%s" "${!a[@]}"
  echo ""
  unset a
done < input.txt
```

Note that this depends on bash 4, due to the associative array. And this one *does* get things in the original order, because bash does a better job of keeping array keys in order than awk.

And I think you've got a solution using `sed` from Jose, though it has a bunch of extra pipe-fitting involved. :)

The last tool you mentioned was `grep`.  I'm pretty sure you can't do this in traditional grep, but perhaps some brave soul might be able to construct a perl-regexp variant (i.e. `grep -P`) using `-o` and lookarounds.  They'd need more coffee than is in me right now though.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution,

```
while read line; do 
  grep -o . <<< $line | sort -u | paste -s -d '\0' -;
done < file
```

`grep -o .` convert 'row line' to 'column line'
`sort -u` sort letters and remove repetead letters
`paste -s -d '\0' -` convert 'column line' to 'row line'
`-` as a filename argument to paste to tell it to use standard input.

Comment: Innovative solution! For reference, the first sed script in your pipe could be shortened to `'s/./& /g'`. And `sort | uniq` can usually be replaced with `sort -u`. Also, what if one of the characters to be trimmed on the line is actually a space?

Comment: You're very welcome. Oh, and be careful with `\n` inside your sed script. What you've got now works with GNU sed, but not with the sed that's in FreeBSD, OSX, Solaris, etc.  If you write stuff that isn't portable, it's best to note that fact, or provide alternatives as anubhava did with his GAWK solution.

Comment: Your script gets shorter and shorter! :-D Well done, this looks good. For reference, a slightly lighter-weight way than `awk` to re-assemble your output might be: `paste -s -d '\0' -`. This may also eliminate the need for an `echo` to generate a newline.

Comment: @ghoti thanks again, you're right the paste is much better .... I like to use StackOverflow to learn

Answer (score 3):

One way using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
perl -F -lane 'print do { my %seen; grep { !$seen{$_}++ } @F }' file
```

Results:

```
1234
1
123
12
```

Comment: I'm always intrigued by perl, but it rarely makes sense to me.  Can you explain how this works?

Answer (score 1):

This awk should work:

```
awk -F '' '{delete a; for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[$i]; for (j in a) printf "%s", j; print ""}' file
1234
1
123
12
```

Here:

`-F ''` will break the record char by char giving us single character in `$1`, `$2` etc.

**Note:** For non-gnu awk use:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=""} {delete a; for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[$i]; 
        for (j in a) printf "%s", j; print ""}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\B/\n/g;s/.*/echo "&"|sort -u/e;s/\n//g' file
```

Split each line into a series of lines. Unique sort those lines. Combine the result back into a single line.

Comment: Perfect! Could you please explain this part `s/.*/echo "&"`.

Comment: @user1436187 see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Extended-Commands) for the `e` command. It allows the pattern space to be evaluated in the current shell and the result placed back in the pattern space.

Answer (score 0):

Unique and sorted alternative to the others, using sed and gnu tools:

```
sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' file | sort | uniq
```

which produces one character per line;  If you want those on one line, just do:

```
sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' file | sort | uniq | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g;'
```

This has the advantage of showing the characters in sorted order, rather than order of appearance.